# Flex 4: Component move event

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a *CustomTextInput* component based on *TextInput* (Spark) component. The instance of this class is placed on a popup window (*TitleWindow*).

**How can I capture the popup move (dragging the title) event inside *CustomTextInput* implementation?**

*MoveEvent.MOVE* event of the *CustomTextInput* itself doesn't work. Of course, I can't access the parent popup window inside the component implementation, because it's a common component that can be used not only on the popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the parent title window notify the inner component? It would require making a custom TitleWindow component, but it seems the most logical way to implement this behavior.